# Character walks too fast when browser's hardware acceleration is turned off

Tags: unity, webgl, unity-webgl, hardware-acceleration, deltatime

I have posted a project on itch.io ([here](https://vmrfreitas.itch.io/cavemapgen)). **My character walks with the speed I intended when Chrome's hardware acceleration is turned on but walks much faster when it is turned off**. First, my friend tested on his PC and I thought it was about different devices, but when I toggle hardware acceleration on and off the problem shows on my PC as well...

Here is the code I have used to move the character:

```
void Update()
{
    change = Vector3.zero;
    change.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    change.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("attack") && currentState != PlayerState.attack){
        StartCoroutine(AttackCo());
    } else if(currentState == PlayerState.walk){
        UpdateAnimationAndMove();
    }
}

void MoveCharacter()
{
    change.Normalize();
    myRigidbody.MovePosition(
        transform.position + change.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime
        );
}

void UpdateAnimationAndMove()
{
    if (change != Vector3.zero){
        MoveCharacter();
        animator.SetFloat("moveX", change.x);
        animator.SetFloat("moveY", change.y);
        animator.SetBool("moving", true);
    } else {
        animator.SetBool("moving", false);
    }
}
```

Here's the character walking at normal speed (hardware acceleration turned on):

[image: normal speed]

Here's the character walking super fast (hardware acceleration turned off):

[image]

Moreover, on my friend's PC, it was moving so fast he'd clip through walls.

Comment: Where and how do you call the `MoveCharacter()` method? There doesn't seem to be a direct call to it anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: @Philipp oops, edited! Forgot to add the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

Quoting [this discussion thread](https://discussions.unity.com/t/once-for-all-is-time-deltatime-good-or-bad-with-input-getaxis/248682): "Inputs are provided by the player on a frame-by-frame basis. They never need to be scaled based on framerate, since you don’t want the same mouse movement to have an arbitrary effect in-game."

I just removed `* Time.deltaTime` from the `MoveCharacter` method and now his speed is consistent through devices.